# Excel Formula_Matching

Tags: excel, pattern-matching, match

I am trying to build an excel formula, that will reference another column based off of the first word. The first word does not need to have an exact match, it will however, need to find words that are “very similar” to each other. If the words, are not a close match, I would need the original cell to show in the results tab (as seen below). I would need the excel formula to do the following:

### Column A......….Column B (with desired info)......….Column C (results)

Upper Body...……….Upper...………………......………………......……Upper

---

Upper Arms...…………….....………………......………………......……   Upper

---

Upper Legs...…………….....………………......………………......……   Upper

---

Lower Legs...…………….....………………......………………......……   Lower Legs

I have tried, the VLookup with the range lookup, as “True”, however the above example will be a lot more complex, with the real data set I am using. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: VLookup can't do fuzzy match. Perhaps see the [Microsoft Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15011).

Answer (score 0):

You can extract first word and then use Index() and Match().

You will first need to get the first word of column A. You can do this by splitting column A by a delimiter (split after first space) or by using a formula.

Formula example: =IF(ISERR(FIND(" ",A2)),"",LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1)) where A2 is the cell you are looking at.

When you have that value you can then use =Index(Match()) to look up value. Match allows for fuzzy matching as long as you do not set the last parameter to 0.

Comment: Thanks for advice, how about if the value that I am trying to refer to, is in a range (in my case a column)?

Comment: Can you write that formula, reference one cell from that range, and then drag the formula down so the next cell in the result column reference the next cell in that range and so on?